# how to sum all the consummations for a specific client that is a foreign key in the consummation model?

Tags: python, django

```
class Consommation(models.Model):
    entree = models.ForeignKey(Entree, models.CASCADE, verbose_name="L'entree", null=True, blank=True)
    food = models.ForeignKey(Meals, models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Plat de resistance', null=True, blank=True)
    dessert = models.ForeignKey(Dessert, models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Dessert', null=True, blank=True)
    boisson = models.ForeignKey(Boisson, models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Boisson', null=True, blank=True)
    autres = models.ForeignKey(Autres, models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Snacks', null=True, blank=True)
    consomme_le = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)
    vipcustomer = models.ForeignKey(VipCustomer, models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,
                                    verbose_name='Client prestigieux', related_name='vip_consommations')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('clients:consommation_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Consommation numero :' + str(self.id)

    @staticmethod
    def get_nom(item, _default=' '):
        if item:
            return item.nom
        return _default

    @staticmethod
    def get_price(item, _default=0):
        if item:
            return item.price
        return _default


    def total_consommation(self):
        get_price = Consommation.get_price
        return get_price(self.entree) + get_price(self.food) + get_price(self.dessert) + get_price(
            self.boisson) + get_price(self.autres)
```

I tried this to get the total of consummation of a client:

```
def total(self):
    return self.vipcustomer.vip_consommations.annotate(Sum(self.total_consommation()))
```

in the template I have this:

```
{% for consommation in vipcustomer.vip_consommations.all %}
<ul>
    <li>
       <a href="{% url 'clients:consommation_detail' pk=consommation.pk %}">
    </li>
</ul>
{% endfor %}
Total : <strong>{{ vipcustomer.vip_consommations.total}} MRO</strong>
```

How to sum the consummations for a vipcustomer that is foreign key to the consummation?

Answer (score 0):

By design, your implementation is not good at all.

You should use at least 2 models for achieving what you are trying to, and I'd even say 3 :

- Consommation with many2many relation with 'Food' class.
- Food ((name it how you want) which will be your different foods) with foreign key to FoodCategory
- FoodCategory (name it how you want)

Otherwise, that means you can only have a Consommation with 1 dessert. What if I want to take 2 desserts ?

With that said, you can easily retrieve the total of a "Consommation", by browsing a queryset that holds every 'Food' linked to your Consommation. You can do that in a [python property](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#properties) (because everything that can be computed do not need to be stored (ideally))

Comment: thanks, I'll try what suggested, and yes it's dirty code, I'm new at it, and i need those critics to improve my skills, thanks

Comment: No problem ;-). Do not hesitate to ask if you encounter any other problem !